# Database for full text search needed. SQL vs NoSQL?

Tags: .net, sql, database, full-text-search, nosql

I know there are several postings about this topic on stackoverflow, but the requirements of them were a bit different.

I'm looking for a database which is eligible for full text search, the main criteria is a short duration of the query and it should run on a Windows 2008 Server with appropriate drivers for .NET.
I am open-minded for all kind of software as long as its free - the only exception in terms of costs is MSSQL Server 2008 because I already have some licences for it.

I assume there is no free SQL-based database that performs a better full text search than MS SQL Server, so the question is if there is any NOSQL-product that is free and can beat MS SQL Server in terms of full text search.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you should check and compare Lucene or Solr (which based on lucene) as your indexing engine.

You can use SQL Server to store your data (the data that should be indexed in FTS and all the metadata and the relationship between tables etc) and just do the indexing with Lucene (if the results of your check will show that it's significantly better than FTS)

Answer (score 1):

MSSQL has good enough built-in Full-Text search and this I would say would be a good start.

Later as your data size will grow up and you finalize requirements for search queries you could install an external Full-Text search engine like [Lucene/SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#about) which will provide you more powerful, relevant and fast Full-Text search and therefore could offload you database from some types of queries.

Sphinx has native built-in MSSQL support along with [Sphinx .NET client](http://code.google.com/p/sphinx-dotnet-client/).